# How do I embed data from a Python DataFrame into an email I am writing within the program in HTML?

Tags: python, html, pandas, email, win32com

I am writing a .py program in PyCharm and one of the things it does is pull in a .csv, does some transformation and puts it into a data frame then checks for null values in each column's rows and checks for null values in each rows columns.  The results of those two functions are placed into separate series variables.

Below in the program I am writing code in Python and HTML that sends an email and I would like the data from the two series' described above to be embedded in the email for reporting purposes.

I just can't figure out how to get the data in the series' tagged or embedded  in the HTML code correctly so that it is displayed in the email when it is sent.

**Data Import:**

```
# imports data and transforms
df = pd.read_excel('P:xxxx\\xxxx\\.xlsx')
df
```

**Counting null values:**

```
# imports pandas
import pandas as pd


# Creates a counting function
def num_missing(num):
    return sum(num.isnull())

#  Applying per column
str1=("Missing values per column:")
str2 = (df.apply(num_missing, axis=0)) # defines that function is to be 
applied on each column 
str2

num_rows = df.shape[0]
num_rows

#  Applying per row #function that looks for blank value and that is the 
last row
str3=("Missing values per row:")
str4=(df.apply(num_missing, axis=1).head(num_rows)) # defines that function 
is to be applied on each row, needs to be able to automatically count to the 
last row with data
str4

missPerCol = pd.DataFrame(str2)
missPerRow = pd.DataFrame(str4)
```

**Email:**

```
#####Send an email notification to desired end users#################################################
#####################################################################################################

import win32com.client as win32
outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'xxxx@xxxx.com'
#mail.CC = 'xxxx@xxxx.com' #'xxxx@xxxx.com'
mail.Subject = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX *DRAFT*'
mail.Body = 'Test message'

mail.HTMLBody = """<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"> <!-- utf-8 works for most cases -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"> <!-- Forcing initial-scale shouldn't be necessary -->
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> <!-- Use the latest (edge) version of IE rendering engine -->
    <meta name="x-apple-disable-message-reformatting">  <!-- Disable auto-scale in iOS 10 Mail entirely -->
    <title>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</title> <!-- The title tag shows in email notifications, like Android 4.4. -->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : BEGIN -->
    <!-- NOTE: If web fonts are not required, lines 10 - 27 can be safely removed. -->

    <!-- Desktop Outlook chokes on web font references and defaults to Times New Roman, so we force a safe fallback font. -->
    <!--[if mso]>
        <style>
            * {
                font-family: sans-serif !important;
            }
        </style>
    <![endif]-->

    <!-- All other clients get the webfont reference; some will render the font and others will silently fail to the fallbacks. More on that here: http://stylecampaign.com/blog/2015/02/webfont-support-in-email/ -->
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
    <!-- insert web font reference, eg: <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!--<![endif]-->

    <!-- Web Font / @font-face : END -->

    <!-- CSS Reset : BEGIN -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Remove spaces around the email design added by some email clients. */
        /* Beware: It can remove the padding / margin and add a background color to the compose a reply window. */
        html,
        body {
            margin: 0 auto !important;
            padding: 0 !important;
            height: 100% !important;
            width: 100% !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops email clients resizing small text. */
        * {
            -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
        }

        /* What it does: Centers email on Android 4.4 */
        div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] {
            margin: 0 !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Stops Outlook from adding extra spacing to tables. */
        table,
        td {
            mso-table-lspace: 0pt !important;
            mso-table-rspace: 0pt !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Fixes webkit padding issue. Fix for Yahoo mail table alignment bug. Applies table-layout to the first 2 tables then removes for anything nested deeper. */
        table {
            border-spacing: 0 !important;
            border-collapse: collapse !important;
            table-layout: fixed !important;
            margin: 0 auto !important;
        }
        table table table {
            table-layout: auto;
        }

        /* What it does: Uses a better rendering method when resizing images in IE. */
        img {
            -ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;
        }

        /* What it does: A work-around for email clients meddling in triggered links. */
        *[x-apple-data-detectors],  /* iOS */
        .x-gmail-data-detectors,    /* Gmail */
        .x-gmail-data-detectors *,
        .aBn {
            border-bottom: 0 !important;
            cursor: default !important;
            color: inherit !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            font-size: inherit !important;
            font-family: inherit !important;
            font-weight: inherit !important;
            line-height: inherit !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Prevents Gmail from displaying an download button on large, non-linked images. */
        .a6S {
           display: none !important;
           opacity: 0.01 !important;
       }
       /* If the above doesn't work, add a .g-img class to any image in question. */
       img.g-img + div {
           display: none !important;
       }

       /* What it does: Prevents underlining the button text in Windows 10 */
        .button-link {
            text-decoration: none !important;
        }

        /* What it does: Removes right gutter in Gmail iOS app: https://github.com/TedGoas/Cerberus/issues/89  */
        /* Create one of these media queries for each additional viewport size you'd like to fix */

        /* iPhone 4, 4S, 5, 5S, 5C, and 5SE */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-width: 374px) {
            .email-container {
                min-width: 320px !important;
            }
        }
        /* iPhone 6, 6S, 7, 8, and X */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-width: 413px) {
            .email-container {
                min-width: 375px !important;
            }
        }
        /* iPhone 6+, 7+, and 8+ */
        @media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) {
            .email-container {
                min-width: 414px !important;
            }
        }

    </style>
    <!-- CSS Reset : END -->

    <!-- Progressive Enhancements : BEGIN -->
    <style>

        /* What it does: Hover styles for buttons */
        .button-td,
        .button-a {
            transition: all 100ms ease-in;
        }
        .button-td:hover,
        .button-a:hover {
            background: #e0301e !important;
            border-color: #555555 !important;
        }

        /* Media Queries */
        @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {

            .email-container {
                width: 100% !important;
                margin: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces elements to resize to the full width of their container. Useful for resizing images beyond their max-width. */
            .fluid {
                max-width: 100% !important;
                height: auto !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Forces table cells into full-width rows. */
            .stack-column,
            .stack-column-center {
                display: block !important;
                width: 100% !important;
                max-width: 100% !important;
                direction: ltr !important;
            }
            /* And center justify these ones. */
            .stack-column-center {
                text-align: center !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Generic utility class for centering. Useful for images, buttons, and nested tables. */
            .center-on-narrow {
                text-align: center !important;
                display: block !important;
                margin-left: auto !important;
                margin-right: auto !important;
                float: none !important;
            }
            table.center-on-narrow {
                display: inline-block !important;
            }

            /* What it does: Adjust typography on small screens to improve readability */
            .email-container p {
                font-size: 17px !important;
            }
        }

    </style>
    <!-- Progressive Enhancements : END -->

    <!-- What it does: Makes background images in 72ppi Outlook render at correct size. -->
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
    <xml>
        <o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
            <o:AllowPNG/>
            <o:PixelsPerInch>96</o:PixelsPerInch>
        </o:OfficeDocumentSettings>
    </xml>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body width="100%" bgcolor="#e0301e" style="margin: 0; mso-line-height-rule: exactly;">
    <center style="width: 100%; background: #222222; text-align: left;">

        <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : BEGIN -->
        <div style="display: none; font-size: 1px; line-height: 1px; max-height: 0px; max-width: 0px; opacity: 0; overflow: hidden; mso-hide: all; font-family: sans-serif;">
            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
        </div>
        <!-- Visually Hidden Preheader Text : END -->

        <!-- Email Header : BEGIN -->
        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 20px 0; text-align: center">
                   <!-- <img src="http://placehold.it/200x50" width="200" height="50" alt="alt_text" border="0" style="height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555;">
                   -->
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!-- Email Header : END -->

        <!-- Email Body : BEGIN -->
        <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="600" style="margin: auto;" class="email-container">

            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                    <img src="C:\\Users\\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX\\XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.jpg" width="600" height="" alt="alt_text" border="0" align="center" style="width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555; margin: auto;" class="g-img">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- Hero Image, Flush : END -->

            <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 40px 40px 20px; text-align: center;">
                    <h1 style="margin: 0; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 24px; line-height: 125%; color: #333333; font-weight: normal;">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0 40px 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555; text-align: center;">
                    <p style="margin: 0;">Report Contents:  XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#ffffff" style="padding: 0 40px 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555;">
                    <!-- Button : BEGIN -->
            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" style="margin: auto">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="border-radius: 3px; background: #222222; text-align: center;" class="button-td">
                                <a href="http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com" style="background: #222222; border: 15px solid #222222; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 110%; text-align: center; text-decoration: none; display: block; border-radius: 3px; font-weight: bold;" class="button-a">
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style="color:#ffffff;">PartnerNet</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                </a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!-- Button : END -->
                </td>
            </tr>
            <!-- 1 Column Text + Button : END -->

            <!-- Background Image with Text : BEGIN -->
            <tr>
                <!-- Bulletproof Background Images c/o https://backgrounds.cm -->
                <td bgcolor="#222222" valign="middle" style="text-align: center; background-position: center center !important; background-size: cover !important;">
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                <v:rect xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" fill="true" stroke="false" style="width:600px;height:175px; background-position: center center !important;">
                <v:fill type="tile" color="#222222" />
                <v:textbox inset="0,0,0,0">
                <![endif]-->
                <div>
                    <table role="presentation" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="middle" style="text-align: center; padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #ffffff;">
                                <p style="margin: 0;">NEED TO FILL THIS SPACE WITH CONTENT</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                </v:textbox>
                </v:rect>
                <![endif]-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Background Image with Text : END -->

        <!-- 2 Even Columns : BEGIN -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center" valign="top" style="padding: 10px;">
                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                        <td class="stack-column-center">
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center">                                                                        
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/270"  width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid" style="height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                        <p style="margin: 0;">Missing values per row for each column</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <!-- Column : END -->
                        <!-- Column : BEGIN -->
                        <td class="stack-column-center">
                            <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding: 10px; text-align: center">
                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/270" width="270" height="270" alt="alt_text" border="0" class="fluid" style="height: auto; background: #dddddd; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555;">
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 13px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555; padding: 0 10px 10px; text-align: left;" class="center-on-narrow">
                                        <p style="margin: 0;">Missing values per column for each row</p>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <!-- Column : END -->
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 2 Even Columns : END -->

        <!-- Clear Spacer : BEGIN -->
        <tr>
            <td aria-hidden="true" height="40" style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- Clear Spacer : END -->

        <!-- 1 Column Text : BEGIN -->
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#ffffff">
                <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding: 40px; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 20px; line-height: 140%; color: #555555; align: center">
                            XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <!-- 1 Column Text : END -->

    </table>
    <!-- Email Body : END -->

    <!-- Email Footer : BEGIN -->
    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%" style="max-width: 680px; font-family: sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-size: 12px; line-height: 140%;">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding: 40px 10px; width: 100%; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 140%; text-align: center; color: #ffffff;" class="x-gmail-data-detectors">
                <webversion style="color: #cccccc; text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;">View as a Web Page</webversion>
                <br><br>
                XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX<br>(xxx) xxx-xxx
                <br><br>
                <unsubscribe style="color: #ffffff; text-decoration: underline;">unsubscribe</unsubscribe>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Email Footer : END -->

    <!-- Full Bleed Background Section : BEGIN -->
    <table role="presentation" bgcolor="#888888" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" align="center" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td valign="top" align="center">
                <div style="max-width: 600px; margin: auto;" class="email-container">
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
                    <tr>
                    <td>
                    <![endif]-->
                    <table role="presentation" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="padding: 40px; text-align: left; font-family: sans-serif; font-size: 12px; line-height: 140%; color: #ffffff;">
                                <p style="margin: 0;">XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <!--[if mso]>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- Full Bleed Background Section : END -->

    </center>
</body>
</html> """

mail.Send()
```

Comment: I think you need some template engine like [`Jinja2`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `df.to_html()`. It converts your data frame to HTML format:

```
mailBody = """<html>
                  <div>%s</div>
                   ......
                  <div>%s</div>
              </html>""" % (misPerCol.to_html(), misPerRow.to_html())
```

Here `dataframe` is the CSS class for setting your table formatting which will look like something like this:

```
 .dataframe{ role:presentation; 
             align:center; 
             border:0; 
             cellpadding:0; 
             cellspacing:0; 
             width:100%
           }
```

Comment: I tried df.to_html but I couldn’t figure where I actually place that code so that the data is displayed in the email correctly.

Comment: For example, if I used those two blocks of code you suggested above, where would I place them in the code?  I've tried all different combinations with strange results that are not what I'm looking for.

Comment: Similar to what I did, asign the string that you create to `mail.HTMLBody`. In the string put `%s` where you want your tables to be seen. You can check how the string looks by printing it with `print(mail.HTMLBody)`.